# How to make an image follows scrolling until a certain point

Tags: css

On my attempt of making an image follows the browser's scrolling, I used the following CSS:

```
position: fixed;
```

This makes it follow the scroll all the way from the top to the bottom. I would like it to follow the scroll as long as it's completely inside the `div`. For example, if the bottom of the image hits the bottom of the `div`, I need it to stop scrolling. Same thing with the top.

I would like to know if this can be achieved in pure CSS, or if I need JavaScript, How I can make this work?

Comment: not possible with css. css is for styling. it's only "interactivity" with the dom is with things like `:hover`. you need javascript to detect where the page has scrolled to, and have it trigger changes in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to calculate the limit where the image will scroll, using the position of the next div.

```
(function($) {
var element = $('#scrollingDiv'),
    originalY = element.offset().top;

var socialelement =  $('#social-area'),
    limitY = socialelement.position().top;

// Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
var topMargin = 40;

// Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
element.css('position', 'relative');

$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var CurrentY = scrollTop + element.outerHeight(true) + topMargin;   
    var MoveUp = limitY < CurrentY ? CurrentY - limitY : 0 ;

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin - (MoveUp / 2)
        }, 500);
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can easily *query the scroll position* using

```
   $(document).scroll(function() {
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
      console.log(scrollPos);
   });
```

and accordingly `removeClass()`, or perform whatever operations you want to do

Comment: jQuery is useful but it should not be the "goto advice" unless specifically asked.  See: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: I apologize if you cannot take constructive criticism, but you should learn the rules of Stack Overflow before openly engaging in conversation through comments.  Stack Overflow is open to users from all countries, including Cyprus, but abusive, lewd, rude, or crude comments are not tolerated.  Please consider this in the future.

Comment: Terrfic and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you have questions regarding the site, please refer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com or http://meta.stackexchange.com, which should help you with any confusion you have, which is not addressed in the StackOveflow Help (http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Nicholas, I think you are confused.  What I did was not retaliation, I reviewed your profile and down-voted only one question, I also up-voted one question and an answer - while I disagreed with your comment, I have no problem receiving down votes, if that is what the community thinks.  Regarding your inappropriate comments, I flagged them because you are 28 years old and acting like you're 13 with comments like "little man" and "alligator", which I consider rude/offensive.  The admin reviewing agreed and if you have an issue with that, please seek advice from http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @vol7ron If you consider 'alligator' offensive, maybe it's not the time yet to browse the Internet - In any case, my apologies if I hurt your feelings but that doesn't give you a reason to go through my 3 year-old questions and start down-voting like crazy. I'd rather you don't reply because I hate wasting time on silly stuff - People have more important things to do than holding grudges on an online QA site

Comment: Nicholas, I found the phrase that you used for that particular comment to be rude.  Again, it's not just me, since the admin validated the flag.  Also, down-voting this one question is not by any means "crazy"… it's from April.  You should also keep in mind that I've reached more people on this site and am not the only one that browse other users profile and go back and review old answers/questions.  It's quite possible that you disturbed some unknown person that I've helped before.  Your continual need to respond shows me that you're upset, which I'm sorry, but has not been my intent.

Comment: But, let me also point out how hypocritical your comment is.  You did not like my answer because the link inside it could go down.  Meaning years from now, people that look at that answer may not be able to follow it.  However, you don't like someone going back a couple months to vote on your question/answer?  You support longevity, unless it applies you.

Comment: @vol7ron I think you should chill out and stop posting on this thread - I consider this to be over and so should you.